# Building a project in Intellij Community works but with Maven doesn't

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build

It sounds strange, I know. But when I am executing a `mvn clean install` on a java reactive project, it failed. The logs indicated that execution on a reactive test method was completed and as in its Test you wrote AssertNotComplete then a error emerges.

I changed from AssertNotComplete to AssertComplete in that test and at the end triggered an error (an opposite), indicated that the reactive test method was not Completed.
But when I executed clean install on Intellij It's Successfully Build. Some clues?

Thanks in advance.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 8, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.969 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.banknational.zeus.services.channel.providedservicepayment.util.CardUtilsTest
[ERROR] com.banknational.zeus.services.channel.providedservicepayment.util.CardUtilsTest.test_ListProducts_Different_FamilyCode_OK  Time elapsed: 0.055 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Completed! (latch = 0, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 1)
        at com.banknational.zeus.services.channel.providedservicepayment.util.CardUtilsTest.test_ListProducts_Different_FamilyCode_OK(CardUtilsTest.java:137)
```

I have changed the line in the file where the logs showed error but it didn't worked.
I restart my Intellij, free cache, I suspected that It probably did not work well. But at the end I did not find an error.

Comment: You can try skipping tests with `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.